# Polymorphic classes in templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Let's say we have a class hierarchy where we have a generic `Animal` class, which has several classes directly inherit from it (such as `Dog`, `Cat`, `Horse`, etc..).

When using templates on this inheritance hierarchy, is it legal to just use `SomeTemplateClass<Animal>` and then shove in Dogs and Cats and Horses into this templated object?

For example, assume we have a templated `Stack` class, where we want to host all sorts of animals.  Can I simply state `Stack<Animal> s;  Dog d; s.push(d);  Cat c; s.push(c);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer of your question if No. But you can use `SomeTemplateClass<Animal*>` and pass pointers of objects of derived classes to it.

For example, if you have a templated Stack class, where you want to host all sorts of animals. You can simply do following:

```
Stack<Animal*> s; 
Dog d; 
s.push(&d); 
Cat c; 
s.push(&c)
```

Comment: For containers of pointers, I can only recommend to use the Boost Pointer Containers as a base. It's like smart pointers, but for multiple objects and with the usualy mix of properties you've come to expect from the STL.

Answer (score 3):

No, you'd have to use pointers, i.e. `Stack<Animal*>` (or some kind of smart pointer). The reason is that `Dog`, `Cat`, `Horse` etc. are not necessarily the same size, since they might add member variables.

The container may allocate space that is only large enough to store an `Animal`. If a `Dog` is larger than that, the container will try to copy-construct a `Dog` that is pushed into it in too small a space, potentially causing memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

NO `Stack<Animal>` and  `Stack<Dog>` are completely different classes.

You can't even cast between `Stack<Animal>` and `Stack<const Animal>`.

Edit: But as @Mihran pointed you can try to use `Stack<Animal* >` instead `Stack<Animal>`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what use the template does with the passed type. If you mean standard containers (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::map` and so on) then the answer is no. There is no relation at all between `std::vector<Animal>` and `std::vector<Dog>` even if in your class hierarchy dogs derive from animals.

You cannot put a `Dog` in an `std::vector<Animal>`... C++ uses copy semantic and you would incur in what is called "[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c/274634#274634)" that means that your `Dog` instance will lose any member that is not also present in the base `Animal` class.

However in general it's of course well possible for a template to use the type in different ways that will allow therefore accept instances of derived classes. For example in the following code the template `MethodCaller` can be instantiated with a type but using an instance of a derived type and correctly handling late binding dispatch. This is possible because the `MethodCaller` instance only holds a *reference* and doesn't make a copy of the object.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
struct MethodCaller
{
    T& t;
    void (T::*method)();
    MethodCaller(T& t, void (T::*method)())
        : t(t), method(method)
    {}
    void operator()() { (t.*method)(); }
};

struct Animal { virtual void talk() = 0; };
struct Dog : Animal { virtual void talk() { printf("Bark\n"); } };
struct Cat : Animal { virtual void talk() { printf("Meow\n"); } };
struct Crocodile : Animal { virtual void talk() { printf("??\n"); } };

void makenoise(Animal *a)
{
    MethodCaller<Animal> noise(*a, &Animal::talk);
    noise(); noise(); noise();
}

int main()
{
    Dog doggie;
    Cat kitten;
    Crocodile cocco;
    makenoise(&doggie);
    makenoise(&kitten);
    makenoise(&cocco);
}
```

It is also possible to implement the `Stack` class as you want...

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Stack
{
    std::vector<T *> content;
    ~Stack()
    {
        for (int i=0,n=content.size(); i<n; i++)
            delete content[i];
    }

    template<class S>
    void push(const S& s)
    {
        content.push_back(new S(s));
    }

    template<class S>
    S pop()
    {
        S result(dynamic_cast<S&>(*content.back()));
        content.pop_back();
        return result;
    }

private:
    // Taboo
    Stack(const Stack&);
    Stack& operator=(const Stack&);
};

int main()
{
    Dog doggie;
    Cat kitten;
    Crocodile cocco;

    Stack<Animal> s;
    s.push(doggie);
    s.push(kitten);
    s.push(cocco);

    Crocodile cocco2 = s.pop<Crocodile>();
    Cat kitten2 = s.pop<Cat>();
    Dog doggie2 = s.pop<Dog>();
}
```

Note that in the implementation I've used an `std::vector` for keeping **pointers** to animals and therefore to avoid the slicing problem. I've been using a template method to be able to accept derived types in the push call.

Also note that when popping animals you must provide what is the class and if it's a wrong one (e.g. you pop out a `Crocodile` when the top element on the stack is a `Dog`) you will get a `bad_cast` exception at runtime.